# Can we choose not to generate views by Entity?

Tags: codefluent

We have a lots of Entity and we are trying to limit the number of SQL objects generated by CodeFluent Entity. We are using some lightViews but I have the feeling that a lot of generated views are useless.
Is it possible to decide Entity by entity to produce view or not ? (I'm aware of the produceViews option on the SQL producer but we still need some views)

Answer (score 0):

No this is not an option. The produceViews attribute only related to persistent views explicitly defined in your model.

Now : if you are completely in control of what you can use, sure you are not referencing some default generated views in any model attribute, any methods (CFSQL or raw SQL), or partial code, then here some ideas :

You can choose not to use the default generated xx_views.sql :
 - do not keep it in sourcecontrol
 - provide your own views (the persistent known ones extraceted from the generated file) in a custom post SQL script  **after_[DefaultNamespace]_views.sql** : in it you could for instance delete all existing views, then declare only the ones you want to use. It would be a manual step that can be time consuming if your persistent views are changing a lot between versions. May be a good name convention for persistent views will help this manual report for a good enough solution.

Another more advanced and cleaner idea would be to provide a **custom aspect** removing the "default" view created for each entity in the meta model before production (see infered meta model and CodeFluent.Model.Entity class), except for entities marked with a custom attribute. This is an idea not guaranted/tested.